# Echo date interval in a PHP calendar

Tags: php, dateinterval

I am creating a calendar and I am in a dire need of a solution. There are records of information in the database and the code reads these records. Two columns hold a `date from` and a `date to`. I have to output these dates that appear in the database in different colors. I have tried many times. And the problem is that the code outputs either the last record that it can fetch in the database or all the date periods however these periods get duplicated based on how many rows are there in the database.[Here is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spyfD.png)

```
<div id="calender_section_top">
            <ul>
                <li>Mon</li>
                <li>Tue</li>
                <li>Wed</li>
                <li>Thu</li>
                <li>Fri</li>
                <li>Sat</li>
                <li>Sun</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="calender_section_bot">
            <ul>
            <?php
$dateYear = ($year != '') ? $year : date("Y");
$dateMonth = ($month != '') ? $month : date("m");
$date = $dateYear . '-' . $dateMonth . '-01';
$currentMonthFirstDay = date("N", strtotime($date));
$totalDaysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dateMonth, $dateYear);
$totalDaysOfMonthDisplay = ($currentMonthFirstDay == 7) ? ($totalDaysOfMonth) : ($totalDaysOfMonth + $currentMonthFirstDay);
$boxDisplay = ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay <= 35) ? 35 : 42;
$dayCount = 1;

for ($cb = 1; $cb <= $boxDisplay; $cb++) {
    if (($cb >= $currentMonthFirstDay || $currentMonthFirstDay == 7) && $cb <= ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay - 1)) {
        $duh = array();
        array_push($duh, $dayCount);

        // Current date

        $currentDate = $dateYear . '-' . $dateMonth . '-' . $dayCount;
        $currentDate = strtotime($currentDate);
        $eventNum = 0;
        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM booking_2 GROUP BY date_from ORDER BY COUNT(book2_id) DESC");
        $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        $eventNum = $result->num_rows;
        if ($eventNum > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $date_from = $row['date_from'];
                $date_to = $row['date_to'];
                $time_from = strtotime($date_from);
                $time_fromm = idate('d', $time_from);
                $time_to = strtotime($date_to);
                $time_too = idate('d', $time_to);
                if ($currentDate >= $time_from && $currentDate <= $time_to) {
                    for ($i = $time_from; $i <= $time_to; $i++) {
                        $cope = array();
                        array_push($cope, $dayCount);
                    }

                    echo '<li id="' . $row['book2_id'] . '" style="background-color:#FF3232 !important;" date="' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDate) . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . implode($cope) . '</span>';
                }
            }

            if (!($currentDate >= $time_from && $currentDate <= $time_to)) {
                for ($g = $time_from; $g <= $time_to; $g++) {
                    $duh = array();
                    array_push($duh, $dayCount);
                }

                echo '<li date="' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDate) . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . implode($duh) . '</span>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo '<li date="' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDate) . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . implode($duh) . '</span>';
        }

        echo '</li>';
        $dayCount++;
?>
            <?php
    }
    else { ?>
                <li><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
            <?php
    }
} ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

sorry for TL;DR. But really need help with this. I have tried all the ways I know so if you have a solution can you please be sure that this will work? I believe this is a hard problem to find a solution to.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: As you can see in the picture I added in the question the dates are duplicating. I need all the dates that are "taken" to be visibly shown in the calendar as you can see for the example when the dates from 2018-06-19 to 2018-06-22. Here is a screen-shot of how it should look like: [link] (http://prntscr.com/jrld15) I hope you can see it

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry. Didn't see the repeating dates... You ought to be able to get rid of the repeating dates by changing `if (!($currentDate >= $time_from && $currentDate <= $time_to)) {` to `else if (!($currentDate >= $time_from && $currentDate <= $time_to)) {`

Comment: Sorry, it does not work either. I have tried everything for days now still no avail. I gues this an uncommon problem and noone seems to have interest in it. I will just move on and do other stuff on my site I guess.